# Why do we say "archenemy" differently from "archangel" and "architecture"?

Tags: pronunciation

Like other words that start with "arch-", [***archenemy***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archenemy) is partly derived from *arkhi* or *arkhos* from the Greek (Wikipedia), meaning *chief*. But why is it said differently, using a "ch" sound, from ***archipelago*** and ***archaeology***, which use a "k" sound?

The "ch" in ***archenemy*** is pronounced similar to that in ***archbishop*** and ***archdiocese***, even though they're followed by consonants in the latter, but a vowel the former.

What made it break from the rules?

Comment: Different borrowings at different times by different people with different ideas about how to pronounce things in other languages. There are no "the rules" that anybody follows, and nobody ever thinks they're diverging; they're always correct. It's other people who're wrong.

Comment: Not to be disrespectful, but I thought "the rules" were what this entire site was all about. Else, wouldn't we just be chirping "Great answer!" all the time? Lol, but I get the tongue-in-cheek @JohnLawler ... at least that's what I hope it is.

Comment: When there **are** rules, yes. But (a) often there is simply variation; (b) many people are misinformed about what rules there are; (c) language rules are self-enforcing, like the law of gravity, not statutes that have to be obeyed.

Comment: archipelago has been borrowed from Italian Arcipelago, Archenemy has been created around 1500 , archeology in the 1800. The way of pronouncing neologism or borrowed words varies with time and origin of the word.

Comment: Other than the quip about gravity, I agree with @JohnLawler, language rules--especially pronunciation rules--are a product of the people who speak the language. For example, look at the debate about whether to use [who or whom](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247207/is-whom-correct-in-i-speak-of-him-whom-is/247229#247229). That being said, I have often pronounced all the example words with the "ch" as having a "k" sound.

Comment: @MondoMigs In language, there certainly are rules, but there are so many exceptions. And yes this site is all about helping explicate those rules and exceptions. It's just that English orthography is... a mess, and not exactly language either. It is a hodgepodge of rules followed unconsciously, rules made up by individuals (eg Webster), and arbitrarily random (maybe a pleonasm, maybe not) choices (eg 'isle'), which for loans can be chaotic (eg Ghadafi). English isn't special; for Irish you need to write out 10 letters before you can have one syllable and you still don't know which one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a native speaker, but I see a major difference between **arch-** in **archenemy** or in **archaeology** and even another one to **archipelago**, which would explain the different pronunciations.

In the first case it is used as a prefix. **Enemy** is still a word by itself, as **bishop** or **diocese** are. The **arch-** prefix is used to emphasize the relevance / importance / significance of this special **enemy / diocese / bishop**.
Here **arch-** derives from the Greek **archi- or arkhi- (main, chief)** as you mentioned before.

This is also correct for **archipelago** (archi meaning main), but here it is a word that can only be used as a whole. **Pelago** has no meaning in English. **Archipelago** derives from Italian (where it comes from Greek), so one cannot compare it with **archbishop** etc. It has not been combined from already English words.

In **archaeology** **arch-** is no prefix. Instead **archaeo-** could be counted as one. The word derives from the Greek words archaios (old, archaic) and logos (science).

The difference becomes clearly visible when translating to German:

**Arch**bishop - **Erz**bischof

**Arch**enemy - **Erz**feind

**Arch**diocese - **Erz**diözese

**Archi**pelago - **Archi**pel

**Archaeo**logy - **Archäo**logie

As a prefix to the given words **Erz-** has the same meaning as **arch-**  and like **archipelago** the German word **Archipel** derives from the Italian word. **Archaeology** and **Archäologie** are just the same.

Comment: It would be good if this answer also corrected, rather than perpetuated, the false impression that the prefix in "archenemy" and "archeology" come from the same Greek root. They do not. Greek "archaios" = "ancient", "archo" = "lead". Ultimately they probably come from the same root, but as loanwords into other languages they seem quite distinct in meaning and usage.

Comment: you did not address the word "*archangel*" which is mentioned in the question title and has the same prefix as "*archbishop*" yet pronounced differently.

Comment: @ziggurism I did mention the Greek roots in my answer.

Comment: @billynoah I did not mention it, because I would have pronounced it false myself, since this had to be derived from the same 'arch'. Now I looked it up and I have no explanation apart from it is an inconsistency in the English language. Maybe it was mistaken as an angel of old instead of main.

Comment: @Daniel you’re right; it does. I must have missed it

Comment: The mention of Ger *Erz-* in this answer got me question whether it was always /tz/ in the end, because *Z* wasn't used in Latin and so, like the letter C, could accept various phonetic values perhaps, maybe *tch* as in *arch-[enemy]*; Although, there's a Z Rune. *Erz* otherwise means *ore, iron ore* (cognate in fact); so perhaps the *Erzengel* is a ... core member of the pantheon?

Comment: the "leader" mentioned above is Greek *arkon*, with a kappa, from \*h2erg-; whereas *archaelogy* is written with a Xi in greek, customarily transcribed ch since Roman times (sometimes kh), cp Christ. The archenemy on the other could conceivably be from https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/argaz < \*h3ergh-. "ärgster Feind" is idiomatic German, indeed. The laryngeal h3 usually colors vowels as o (cp orphan < \*h3erbhos-), so what gives?

Comment: And in case that hasn't already confused everyone, consider that Ger *Arsch* "ass" translates *fucker* very well.

Answer (score 3):

Further to John Lawler's comment to the OP: Here is one factor which could explain how come the "arch-" prefixes of *archenemy* and *archangel* are pronounced differently. *Archangel* is derived from the Greek *archangelos*, that is, the compounding was done in Greek. By contrast, *archenemy* was formed in English by combining the English prefix *arch*- and the word *enemy*. True, that prefix was derived from Greek, but its pronunciation has been Anglicised. The same applies to Daniel's examples *archbishop* and *archdiocese*, and also to *archdeacon*, *archduke* and *archlute*.